# Trigger update with if condition

Tags: if-statement, oracle11g, triggers

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TR_SITECONTACT_UPDATE
AFTER  UPDATE OR INSERT  ON s_ct 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_SID s_ct.sid%type;
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN   
IF :NEW.CTID != :OLD.CTID THEN
      UPDATE CT
      SET lastupdatedon =sysdate,
        LASTUPDATESITE=:NEW.SID
      WHERE CTID  = :NEW.CTID;
COMMIT;
END IF;
END;
```

Here it's possible to check whether lastupdatedCOF is null or not then use update statement, before update row i need to check lastupdatedCOF IS NULL OR NOT in CT Table. IF Null means i need to use below update statement

```
UPDATE CT
      SET lastupdatedon =sysdate,
        LASTUPDATESITE=:NEW.SID
      WHERE CTID  = :NEW.CTID;
COMMIT;
```

lastupdatedCOF IS NOT NULL Means

```
UPDATE CT
      SET lastupdatedon =sysdate,
        LASTUPDATESITE=:NEW.SID,
        lastupdatedCOF = NULL
      WHERE CTID  = :NEW.CTID;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why are you shouting? (And why is it so common among SQL questions?)

Comment: @Biffen I need to check condition to another table??

Comment: And that requires shouting?! Are you angry at the table?

Comment: Ha ha Biffen. i am trying to implement one scenario that requires this query..

Comment: Edited your question since you don't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question, either lastupdatedCOF is null (in which case, it remains null) or lastupdated_cof is not null and you want to set it to null.

So, why not just always set it to null?

I.e.:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TR_SITECONTACT_UPDATE
AFTER  UPDATE OR INSERT  ON s_ct 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_SID s_ct.sid%type;
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN   
IF :NEW.CTID != :OLD.CTID THEN
      UPDATE CT
      SET lastupdatedon =sysdate,
        LASTUPDATESITE=:NEW.SID,
        lastupdatedCOF = NULL
      WHERE CTID  = :NEW.CTID;
COMMIT;
END IF;
END;
```

One other point - do you really, really need an autonomous transaction? What if the transaction inserting into/updating the s_ct table is rolled back - as things stand, you'd be left with a row in the CT table that's been changed, despite the underlying change not having taken place.

Comment: Hi Boneist,  Without using Autonomous transaction how u can commit the update statement?? do u think it's possible to commit without pragma??

Comment: A commit or rollback doesn't work on just a single statement, it works on a transaction. That could be a single DML statement, but it could be a series. In your case, the transaction would be the insert into/update of the s_ct table, followed by the triggered update of the ct table (btw, what happens if your :new.ctid doesn't exist in the ct table? Wouldn't it be better to use a merge statement, not an update statement?). When you commit or rollback the transaction, you would commit or rollback both statements.

Comment: I suggest you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/transact.htm#CNCPT038). In general, you only want to use an autonomous transaction when you want something to happen regardless of whether the original transaction was committed or rolled back - e.g. logging an error (if you didn't have the logging code in a different transaction, when the problem transaction is rolled back, you would also rollback the error logging! Not ideal...)